# Force to atomically rebase and non-fast-forward merge using Gerrit/GitLab

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, gerrit

We are deciding to use [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) or [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) for code review.

And here is our commit history guide:

- every task should be developed on another branch, not on the main branch.
- before we submit, we have some works to make sure code quality (e.g. code review)
- use `rebase` and `merge --no-ff` for every branch to clarify the branch commit history (tasks)

The git graph is like this:

[image]

We can read the tasks easily.

### If We Using Gerrit

There is a `rebase` button and [**merge always** (`merge --no-ff`)](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#submit_type) in the project settings, but **I don't know how to make the `rebase` and `merge --no-ff` always be ATOMIC operation by Gerrit**.

It means that, when I submit to merge into the main branch, no one can submit another merge before my two step git operations are done (`rebase` and `merge --no-ff`).

If it is **not atomic**, then after I rebase my branch to the latest commit of the main branch (`HEAD`) and just before I merge into main branch, someone could submit a merge and it will change the `HEAD`.

The git graph will be just like this (two *non-fast-forward merges* from the same commit):

[image]

Is there any way to force to atomically **rebase** and **non-fast-forward merge** using Gerrit?

### If We Using GitLab

There is a GitLab enterprise edition to support `rebase` and `merge --no-ff`, but we choose use community edition.

Is that possible to add the functionality (atomic `rebase` and `merge --no-ff`) to GitLab on our own? Any open-source GitLab plugin for this feature?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to force atomically rebase+submit (in whatever submit method). What about to use the "Rebase If Necessary" method? You'll get a very "clean" history without unnecessary merges, like this:

```
O --- O --- O --- O --- O --- O  <= master branch
       \               /
        O ---- O ---- O          <= task branch
```